# Is the location parameter always equal to $\operatorname{E}(X)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable such that one of the parameters of its distribution is a location parameter. Let's call this location parameter $\mu$ for convenience. Then is it always the case that $E(X) = \mu$?

**Examples:**

1. Most famously, in a Normal$(\mu, \sigma^2)$ random variable, $\mu$ is the location parameter and we have $E(X) = \mu$.
2. Suppose $X$ is a Laplace random variable. Then $X \sim \operatorname{Laplace}(\mu, b)$ where $\mu$ is the location parameter and again we have $E(X) = \mu$.

These are the two examples that immediately came to mind. I'm sure more examples can be found.

Comment: $\mu$ is often used as a location parameter because physically speaking, it represents the "center of mass" of points distributed by the probability distribution. In physics, if you wanted to "move" the probability mass and didn't know where to "push it" a natural spot to start would be the center of mass/expected value, because when you push there, you apply only a linear force, and not an angular one.

Comment: $\mu$ has it's own definition - the term "location parameter" doesn't really have a strict mathematical meaning.

Comment: The log-normal usually has two parameters neither of which is a location parameter.  But it would be easy enough to reparametrise it for example to use $m=\exp(\mu)$ in which case $m$ would be a location parameter representing the median.  Or you could have a shifted exponential distribution with a location parameter indicating the minimum (and mode).

Answer (score 5):

It's not always the case that the mean defines the location parameter. For example the Cauchy distribution does not even have a mean. However, the median gives a well defined location parameter.

In addition, for extreme value distributions such as the Gumbel, the parameter referred to as the location parameter is not always equal to the mean (depending on the value of the shape parameter).

Comment: My question is the opposite: does the location parameter always define the mean?

Comment: I see, so you're interested in cases where the mean is well defined and is equal to the location parameter?

Comment: Updated with a comment on the Gumbel distribution

Comment: Well, yes, is there any distribution with a location parameter such that $E(X) \neq $ location parameter? You mentioned the Gumbel distribution. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

The reason $\mu$ appears in these specifications is that it is convenient to use the mean as one of the parameters when that is possible. In those cases $\mu$ will be the expectation, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

For all symmetric distributions, the expectation, which is on the symmetry axis, is a natural choice for a location and it would be foolish to choose another.

For asymmetric distributions, you may have alternative options to define the location, such as the the median, the midrange, the mode... or even some parameter with no name, and all these may differ from the expectation.

As said by rubikscube09, *location* is an informal concept.